# Enter the USA before going to Canada on a WHV

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, canada

I am a German resident. 
I m in possessision of a Work- and Holiday Visa for Canada, which allowes me to stay and work there for 1 year.
On my way to Canada (Vancouver)I would like to stop in New York for a few days to see some of my friends. 
I do not have a flight back to Germany, since I m planning to fly to Canada and live there for a year.

I read the rules to enter the USA with an ESTA, require a flight out of the country, which can t be Canada, Mexico or nearby islands.

I was wondering if it makes a difference if I  can show my work and holiday visa, as proof that I am going to stay in Canada, to be able to enter the U.S. without a flight back to Germany or any other county besides Canada.

I am looking forward to your answer and hope you can help me.

I think my question is different to the ones showed, because my main issue is, that I don t know if the paper, which shows that I have a work and holiday visa for canada, is enough proof for the U.S. that I intend to stay and live in Canada and to let me into the country without a return flight to germany (or somewhere else). 
I m not worried about the 90days and re-entering the U.S.

Comment: Can you tell us where you read this about needing a flight out of the country?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can fly to Canada, Mexico or some other islands. Those rules concern whether and when you can _return_ to the US from those places.

Comment: @MichaelHampton VWP rules explicitly state that a ticket to Canada is NOT sufficient unless you are a legal resident of Canada.

Comment: @Doc if you look at it as the traveler having authorization to stay in Canada for an extended period, it doesn't much matter whether the traveler has actually begun using that authorization.

Comment: @phoog Agreed, but that's not how the legislation is written.  The rules talk about being a resident in Canada, which technically they aren't.  Thankfully the immigration officials will follow the intent of the law and not the actual wording so it's not overly important.

Comment: @Doc which part of the legislation (or regulations) controls this?

Comment: @phoog 8 U.C.S. 1187 (a)(8) - "Round-trip ticket.  The alien is in possession of a round-trip transportation ticket"

Comment: @Doc but the bit about the trip ending in contiguous territory being okay if the traveler resides there is in the CFR, not the statute.

Comment: Well, i think its about, weather having a workpermit for one year, counts as being a `resident` of canada!?

Comment: Your Canadian visa does state that it is a **temporary resident visa**!

Comment: @MichaelHampton is that written anywhere?

Comment: Oh, you're right, it's not printed on the visa. But it is all over the CIC web site...